# xslt transform sequence with maxOcurs=unbounded to nested elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<person-list>
  <pid>100</pid>
  <pname>Tom Jones</pname>
  <pdescription>Some Text</pdescription>
  <pid>101</pid>
  <pname>John Thomas</pname>
</person-list>
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
<person-list>
  <person>
    <pid>100</pid>
    <pname>Tom Jones</pname>
    <pdescription>Some Text</pdescription>
  </person>
  <person>
    <pid>101</pid>
    <pname>John Thomas</pname>
  </person>
</person-list>
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: The answer is "Yes"! Are you using XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0 though? It always helps to show what XSLT you have tried so far, and also give a bit more explanation about the rules of the transformation. Also, I am not sure how the title of the question, which mentions "sequence with maxOccurs=unbounded", relates to the question itself.

Comment: The XML is defined in my XSD schema with <sequence maxOccurs="unbounded"><element name="pid"> ....
I couldn't come up with a better name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:template match="person-list">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="pid">
      <person>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </person>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this in XSLT1.0 is define a key that groups the non-pid elements under **person-list**, by the first most preceding **pid** element

```
<xsl:key 
   name="fields" 
   match="person-list/*[not(self::pid)]" 
   use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::pid[1])" />
```

Then, for the **person-list** element, you would select just the **pid** elements

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="pid" />
```

And within the template that matches the **pid** you would create a **person** element, and output the other elements using the key:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('fields', generate-id())" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="fields" match="person-list/*[not(self::pid)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::pid[1])" />
   <xsl:template match="person-list">
      <person-list>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="pid" />
      </person-list>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="pid">
      <person>
         <xsl:copy-of select="." />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('fields', generate-id())" />
      </person>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<person-list>
  <person>
    <pid>100</pid>
    <pname>Tom Jones</pname>
    <pdescription>Some Text</pdescription>
  </person>
  <person>
    <pid>101</pid>
    <pname>John Thomas</pname>
    <pdescription></pdescription>
  </person>
</person-list>
```

Note that with approach you could add further fields to you input document for each person without the need for amending the XSLT.

Also note the use of the 'identity transform' to copy existing elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways to do it. You could for instance find the "pid"-elements and then combine them with the following 2 elements using "following-sibling" and remove the copied tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <!-- IdentityTransform -->
 <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
       <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
       </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/person-list/pid">
<person>
  <pid><xsl:value-of select="." /></pid>
  <pname><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*" /></pname>
  <pdescription><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*/following-sibling::*" />    </pdescription>
</person>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/person-list/pname" />
<xsl:template match="/person-list/pdescription"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the <pdescription> element is optional. So I need some dynamic way to figure out when the start the next <person> element.

Comment: then the xslt 2.0 solution supposed by Michael Kay should do the trick - if you are using xslt 2.0 of course

Comment: hm... - I'd appreciate comments to downvotes on working answers